# Does any know how to access this huge nested array?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.4

Does any know how to access this huge nested array?

I’m doing a print_r to come up with this result.

Please look on the image attached to see what I’m referring.

[image]

For example I would like to access the entity_id in that array.

How would I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: and what gives you $yourObject->getData(); ?

Comment: what do you mean? I don't get what your trying to tell me about your question. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to dump the data object and see if the value is already there like print_r($yourObject->getData()); or print_r(get_class_methods($yourObject->getData()));

Comment: actually, that result came from a print_r()

Comment: I can see that but you are dumping the whole object and not the readable data and if you dump all methods then i guess there is a method to get the data you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

extend this class

```
class Foo extends Mage_Catlog..........
{
public function getEntityId()
{
return $this->_ddlCatch[1]['sales_flat_quote']['entity_id'];
}
```

}

Comment: @rakeshS extend "Mage_Catlog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute" since the name of class was long so I used dots instead.

Comment: How does this work? Since the variable `_ddlCatch` is inside the object-variable `Mage_Catlog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::_entity::_read::_ddlCatch` (sorry don't interpret the approach, just a representation). I am just curios to know, can you get a working example and show me how? You could use [Codepad](http://codepad.org/)

Answer (score 2):

The "_entity", "_read", and "_dllCache" objects are protected, hence you can't access them. However, it seems someone has found a hack to exploit eval: [OO PHP protected properties not available in foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646270/oo-php-protected-properties-not-available-in-foreach-loop#answer-5410563)